# How to only show true rows in a vector including NA values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

The basic setting looks as follows:

```
example_data <- data.frame(num=1:5, let=letters[1:5])

complicated_criterium <- function(data) { c(T, NA, F, T, F)}

example_data[complicated_criterium(example_data), ]
```

This shows the following:

```
   num  let
1  1    a
NA NA   <NA>
4  4    d
```

I would like to only see rows 1 and 4, the rows where my complicated criterium is true. What is a simple way to achieve that?

It is correct that the complicated criterium spits on NA on row 2 so I don't want to change that behavior. I played around with is.na and na.omit but logically combining NA with T or F just gives NA again and omitting the NA changes the length of the vector so I don't get the correct rows anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap it in `which()`

```
example_data[which(complicated_criterium(example_data)),]
```

Output:

```
  num let
1   1   a
4   4   d
```

Comment: That is the simple build I didn't know and failed to reprogram myself, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are more elegant ways, but the following base R approach will do the trick:

```
example_data[complicated_criterium(example_data) &
               !is.na(complicated_criterium(example_data)),]

# or

keeps <- complicated_criterium(example_data)
example_data[keeps & !is.na(keeps),]
```

Output:

```
#  num let
#1   1   a
#4   4   d
```

Comment: I thought any logical composition involving NA just gives NA but NA & F gives F, nice.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::filter` drops NAs by default

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

data.frame(x = 1:5) %>% 
  filter(c(TRUE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
#>   x
#> 1 1
#> 2 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>